# What was the first journal to have Feynman Diagrams?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I'm writing a paper on the history of Feynman diagrams and am having trouble finding the first paper published by Feynman which features a calculation done with Feynman Diagrams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comprehensive sources on the history of renormalization are [Cao-Schweber survey paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/20117830) and [Cao's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=d0wS0EJHZ3MC&source=gbs_navlinks_s). On the diagrams specifically the source [Kaiser's Drawing Theories Apart: The Dispersion of Feynman Diagrams in Postwar Physics](http://www.press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/D/bo3534300.html), see also his [interview to American Scientist](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/richard-feynmans-diagrams). According to Kaiser, one of the first published diagrams (reproduced below) appears on p.772 of

Feynman, R. P.: 1949 [The Space-Time Approach to Quantum Electrodynamics](http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Feynman_QED_1949.pdf), Physical Review 76, 769-89.

Stueckelberg might have used them earlier in an unpublished manuscript, the topic is controversial, see [Did Feynman develop QED based on Stueckelberg's manuscript?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/did-feynman-develop-qed-based-on-stueckelbergs-manuscript/3538#3538) The diagrams were a computational tool for the procedure developed in Feynman's seminal renormalization papers published a year earlier. Below are the citations in the order of publication with direct links.

1) Feynman, R. P.: 1948, [Space-time Approach to Non-relativistic Quantum Mechanics](http://web.ihep.su/dbserv/compas/src/feynman48c/eng.pdf), Reviews of Modern Physics 20, 367-87.

2) Feynman, R. P.: 1948, [A Relativistic Cut-off for Classical Electrodynamics](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/3516/1/FEYpr48a.pdf), Physical Review  74, 939-46.

3) Feynman, R. P.: 1948, [Relativistic Cut-off for Quantum Electrodynamics](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/3517/1/FEYpr48b.pdf), Physical Review 74, 1430-38.

None of them had "Feynman diagrams" however, although there is a multiple path picture in the second one.

[image]

Comment: ... and to answer the question, you should say which of these papers had Feynman diagrams in it.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar As it turns out, none :-)

Answer (score 2):

[This paper](http://www.edition-open-access.de/proceedings/5/13/index.html) is an analysis of Feynman's early work with Feynman diagrams, and should help you find the answer. Also look at Freeman Dyson's early papers, where he explains Feynman's techniques.